# css 3d shape becomes skewed on rotate

Tags: css, 3d, css-transforms

I have a 3d box in css and it looks weird when I rotate it. Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/GKPZ9/  
you can see how weird and non-box-like it looks when rotated. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right and it is about the lateral sides looking trapezoidal rather than rectangular when the box is rotated, then...

It's because you used `perspective` on the box which you rotate. Using `perspective` on its parent (the body in this case) should solve the problem. You might also want to set a `perspective-origin` in this case.

### [*modified fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/GKPZ9/3/)

Also, *please note that you should **always put the unprefixed version last***.

And another note: the default value for `backface-visibility` is `visible`, so you can leave that out.

Answer (score 0):

which browser are you using to test the output?

i feel your code is working on webkit browsers but not on firefox, ie etc.

you have used css properties like perspective, transform-style which are supported only by the webkit browsers 
also you have used few css properties like transform,backface-visibility  which are supported by browsers other than webkit types but you haven't specified the properties in a way which other browsers could understand.
for example you just specified

```
transform: rotateX(-20deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateX(-20deg);
```

where you should have specified

> ```
>  -moz-transform: rotateX(-20deg); 
>   -ms-transform: rotateX(-20deg); 
>    -o-transform: rotateX(-20deg); 
>       transform: rotateX(-20deg);
>          -webkit-transform: rotateX(-20deg);
> ```

Comment: Firefox, Opera and IE10 now support transforms without a prefix. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d And `transform-style` is supported by Firefox as well.